# Ajax call is falling to http, despite being on https page

Tags: jquery, ajax, https

I am making a call from a secure page to a relative path (i.e., I'm making the call to something like 'object/id'). I am using jquery's $.ajax to  make the call.

When the action is called, the call makes a request to the same path, but http -- despite the browser being on https. It's breaking everything and I can't understand why.

Code:

```
$.ajax(
            url: 'object/1'
            type: 'PUT',
            data: {data},
            success: ->
              {{stuff}}
          )
```

Comment: You should post the code related to the ajax call.

Comment: What is the value of `$(event.target).closest('tr').attr('data-remote-url')`

Comment: 'object/{id}' -- with the id being a number

Comment: Edited for clarity. The '1' in the url changes depending on the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue ended up being my server did not accept https requests at the action I was calling. The ajax call was fine, it was just getting bumped to http by my server.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls can only make requests back to the server they are originating from to prevent xxs or cross site scripting. You didn't specify if the http site was of the same domain but this sounds like the culprit.

Comment: It's the same server.

Comment: Not being funny but same server or same website domain (ex domainX/dir1 to domainX/dir2)

Comment: Both. Same domain, same server.